# Using a FilteredClassifier with a Bayesian Network in WEKA

Tags: weka

I'm running WEKA from the command line to create a Bayesian network model for training, and then using this model to test on a separate data set. The Bayesian network uses the TAN search option with a simple estimator. My command line call for training looks like this:

```
java -cp weka.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar  
weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet -d BN_model -p 0 -distribution -t tr2.arff -D 
-Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.TAN -- -S BAYES 
-E weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator -- -A 1 > tr_preds
```

Now, I just realized I need to use a a FilteredClassifier since I want to add instance IDs to my test data. This is where I'm stuck. I run the following:

```
java -cp weka.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar 
weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier 
-F weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 1 
-W weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet -d BN_model -p 1 -distribution -t tr2.arff -D 
-Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.TAN -- -S BAYES 
-E weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator -- -A 1 > tr_preds
```

and I get the following error:

```
Weka exception: Illegal options: -S BAYES
```

To trouble shoot, I removed all the fancy search options and estimators, and just ran the Bayesian Network classifier with default settings. This worked fine, but it's obviously not what I need. It's clear that I'm having issues constructing this command line statement properly.

Could you please advise what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much!

Best,
Francisco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your command line arguments are in a wrong order. Because `-- -S BAYES` is the first `--` after `-W`, it thinks this option belongs to `weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet`, which is an illegal option. You forgot the `--` after `-W ...` to specifiy the options of the classifier.

Also, general options like `-t tr2.arff -d BN_model -p 1 -distribution` were placed somewhere in the middle, it is better to place them after the class you're calling:

```
java -cp weka.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar 
weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier
-t tr2.arff -d BN_model -p 1 -distribution
-F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 1"
-W weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet
-- -D -Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.TAN
   -- -S BAYES
   -E weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator
   -- -A 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up getting frustrated with the command line syntax, so I used xml options instead. After fiddling with those, I realized my problem is exactly as you mentioned.